# SQL Getting 2 digit numbers from row_number Over () function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to get the numbers with 2 digits using the following function?

```
Row_number () Over(Order By UH.Stuff) AS HSN
```

I want the query to return 01 , 02 , 03 instead of 1,2,3...

Comment: What about row with number 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UH.Stuff)), 2) AS HSN
```

Comment: What about row with number 100?

Comment: Using this solution, row number 100 will output as "00". Row number 101 will output as "01", and so on. But that was not the question. The question was how to output with only 2 digits, which is exactly what my solution does. I trust that OP knows how many rows his UH.Stuff table contains.

Comment: He only knows how many rows his UH.Stuff table contains *today*. IMHO, one should save the left-padding for the presentation layer, not do it the query.

Comment: @alroc - left-padding at the DB layer can be useful, for example if you want to generate sequential order numbers of type VARCHAR, that should be sortable in ascending order, ("ORD-0001", "ORD-0002", "ORD-0010", etc.), but other than that, I agree. This solutions depends upon the fact that OP knows for sure, that the UH.Stuff is a static table, where the number of records will never exceed 99.

Comment: as far as the logic goes,the numbers here could be only 2 digit numbers so this logic does it for me now,cheers all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `Convert()` function:

To get 2 digits:

```
RIGHT(100 + Row_number () Over(Order By UH.Stuff), 2) AS HSN
```

3 digits:

```
RIGHT(1000 + Row_number () Over(Order By UH.Stuff), 3) AS HSN
```

So on ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to zero-pad numbers in SQL Server:

```
select right(1000000 + Row_number () Over(Order By UH.Stuff), 2) AS HSN
```

What this does is add a big number to your number.  The function `right()` automatically converts it to a string.  The right-most two digits will be zero-padded.